# Reduce the spacing of the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing

How do I reduce the line spacing in my Table of Contents?
I tried with `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}` but it doesn't...

Comment: You should have a look at the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace).

Comment: \begin{spacing}{0.9}
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}                                                          Thank you for help

Comment: You can answer your own question since it seems that you already have solved your problem.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of the spacing environment, you can use also the `tocloft` package for a more granular control. See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{.1ex}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-.5ex}
\usepackage{lipsum} % placeholder text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The chapter one}
\chapter{The chapter two}
\section{Lore ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Nam dui ligula}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Nulla malesuada}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{The chapter three}
\section{Lore ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{The chapter four}
\section{Lore ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use the version of `tocloft` which is part of the `memoir` class, you should use `\cftbeforechapterskip` instead of `\cftbeforechapskip` and `\cftbeforesectionskip` instead of `\cftbeforesecskip`.